# In "find ... | xargs ...", why does xargs iterate even when find returns zero results?

Tags: linux, freebsd, xargs

I recently had a `find ... | xargs ...` use case that surprised me.  The issue involves the case where `find` returns no matches.

Testing on two systems, I found that one behaves as I would expect:

```
$ mkdir empty
$ find empty -type f | wc -l
       0
$ find empty -type f | xargs echo file
$
```

But the other one does not behave as I would expect:

```
$ mkdir empty
$ find empty -type f | wc -l
0
$ find empty -type f | xargs echo file
file
```

What causes the behaviour in the second case, and is there a way around it?  When `find` returns zero matches, I would like `xargs` to iterate zero times.

Comment: Consider [`find … -exec …`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/41740/108618).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's what -r is for in the GNU version:

```
-r, --no-run-if-empty
If the standard input does not contain any nonblanks, do not run the command.  
Normally, the command is run once even if there is no input.  This option is a GNU extension.
```

On FreeBSD this is default behaviour.

Comment: Thank you.  I guess I'll cultivate the habit of always saying `xargs -r` in the future.  What is the use case for the Linux behavior?  I.e. why is this a "feature"?

Comment: Very good question! Unfortunately this is the xargs source commit from 1996 (if I'm reading savannah correctly, I find it confusing!) https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/findutils.git/diff/xargs/xargs.c?id=c030b5ee33bbec3c93cddc3ca9ebec14c24dbe07 and it already has that option.